# Why does ValidateToken generates multiple threads

Tags: .net, api, async-await, jwt, .net-6.0

I really need some input to my problem since I´m stuck... Any help would be appreciated.

So, I´ve developed an API that should use JWT token as authentictation.
I collect public tokens externally and store this in a static variable in the controller class.

And when I do receive a request from client I need to validate JWT token.
I have this code that does the job, but generates multiple threads so the server goes bananas with 100% CPU. The code works, but does not close the threads.
Can anyone understand why? And what I can change?

Below is my controller code and the function generating all the threads after that.

```
 public class TjosanController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly Logger logger = null;
    private IWCConfig IWCConfig { get; set; }
    private APIConfig APIConfig { get; set; }
    private TokenConfig TokenConfig { get; set; }
    private static TokenAuthres Tokens { get; set; }

    public TjosanController(IOptions<IWCConfig> IWCCSettings, IOptions<APIConfig> APISettings, IOptions<TokenConfig> TokenSettings)
    {
        logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Tjosanlogging");
        this.IWCConfig = IWCCSettings.Value;
        this.APIConfig = APISettings.Value;
        this.TokenConfig = TokenSettings.Value;

        //if (Tokens == null)
        //{
        //    Tokens = await loadTokens();
        //}
    }
    
    private async Task<TokenAuthres> loadTokens()
    {
        return await BL.getTokens(this.APIConfig, this.logger);
    }
    
    [HttpGet("messages")]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    public async Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult> method1()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
        Stream respStream = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            //used to get the jwt token from header.
            var stream = await BL.getAccessToken(this.HttpContext, logger);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stream))
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            JwtSecurityToken accessToken = await BL.ReadTokenHeader(stream, logger);

            // keyToUse should be the public token to use
            Key keyToUse = null;

            if (Tokens == null)
            {
                //this should not happen since Tokens is static and shared between users..?
                Tokens = await loadTokens();
            }

            if (Tokens != null)
            {
                foreach (Key k in Tokens.keys)
                {
                    if (k.kid == accessToken.Header.Kid)
                    {
                        if (k.use == TokenConfig.AccetableUseValue)
                        {
                            keyToUse = k;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (keyToUse == null)
                {
                    Tokens = await BL.getTokens(this.APIConfig, logger);

                    foreach (Key k in Tokens.keys)
                    {
                        if (k.kid == accessToken.Header.Kid)
                        {
                            if (k.use == TokenConfig.AccetableUseValue)
                            {
                                keyToUse = k;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (keyToUse == null)
                    {
                        return Unauthorized();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            string validateResult = await BL.ValidateaccessToken(this.TokenConfig, accessToken, logger);

            if (validateResult != "OK")
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            string modulus = keyToUse.n.Clone() as string;
            string exponent = keyToUse.e.Clone() as string;

            //verify Token
            //THIS VERIFYACCESSTOKEN-METHOD IS THE PROBLEM. I´VE COMMENTED OUT EVERYTHING AND WHEN I ADDED THIS BACK THE NBR OFR THREADS INCREASED VERY MUCH
            bool verifyResult = await BL.VerifyAccessToken(this.TokenConfig, modulus, exponent, stream, logger);
            if (verifyResult == false)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            TjosanSession session = await API.getTjosanSession(this.APIConfig, SocialSecurityNumber, IdentificationTime, logger);

            if (session == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            string endpoint = await API.getEndpointForParticipantID(this.APIConfig, session.ParticipantID, logger);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endpoint))
            {
                endpoint = await IWCC.getEndpoint(this.IWCConfig, logger);
            }


            responseMessage =  await getMessages(endpoint, session.ParticipantID, logger);

            if (responseMessage != null && responseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string responseString = String.Empty;

                respStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                reader = new StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                responseString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                GetMessagesRes result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetMessagesRes>(responseString);

                return Ok(result);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex);
            return BadRequest();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (responseMessage != null)
            {
                responseMessage.Dispose();
            }
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
                reader.Dispose();
            }
            if (respStream != null)
            {
                respStream.Close();
                respStream.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the function:

```
public static async Task<bool> VerifyAccessToken(TokenConfig config, string modulus, string exponent, string token, Logger logger)
    {
        try
        {
            if (config == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modulus))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(exponent))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                return false;
            }

            RSAParameters rsaParam = new RSAParameters();

            //rsaParam.Modulus = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key.n);
            rsaParam.Modulus = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(modulus);

            //rsaParam.Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String(key.e);
            rsaParam.Exponent = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(exponent);

            //rsa = RSA.Create(rsaParam);

            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = config.Issuer,
                ValidAudience = config.Audience,
                IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsaParam),
                CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory()
                {
                    CacheSignatureProviders = false
                }
            };

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var validatedSecurityToken);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex);
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
```

TokenConfig is created when controller startup and stores som config-stuff from appsettings.
Logger is a NLog instance.

Does anyone see the problem here?! I´m not getting anywhere so any help/input would be really appreciated.
Again, the code works but does not dispose threads which make the servers run on 100% CPU with many many open threads. And it is the VerifyAccessToklen-method that is causing this. Code is written in .net 6, upgraded from .net core 3.1.

Comment: _"but does not close the threads"_ how have you diagnosed this?

Comment: I use the task manager and can se when I send multiple calls to the api with this function disabled nothing really happens with threads. But when i enable the function again the threads increases a lot and the CPU reaches 100 % with like 2000 calls.

Comment: Windows task manager does not show .NET thread pool statistics.

Comment: But when I send in multiple requests I can see that number of threads increases, and CPU is hitting 100% an stays there.  
What type of thread is it then, if not .Net thread?